# SharePoint 2010 run powershell as a different user

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-server, workflow, powershell

I am trying to start a workflow with Powershell and when I do that it fails on start since its starting the workflow as a System Account

Is there a way to execute the powershell and start workflow as a different user in SharePoint 2010?

I tried opening the SP Management Shell as different user, but it didn't work, it still starts the workflow as system account

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really old article but might help you with this problem: [Workflows do not start.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/victorbutuza/workflows-do-not-start)

Quoting the article:

> you should create a special account **not** SHAREPOINT\SYSTEM, that is a
> site collection owner on the site collection where the workflow is
> hosted, open the workflow in SharePoint Designer while logged on as
> this new account and simply save the workflow without modifying
> anything.

And also run

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn declarativeworkflowautostartonemailenabled -pv true
```

to enable workflows to start using the impersonation scheme.